# Array types checking does not work in nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let test: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 'a'] // correctly fails

let test2 = {
    demo: 1,
    items: <number[]> ['a', 'b'], // correctly fails
}

let test3 = {
    demo: 1,
    items: <number[]> [1, 2, 3, 'a'], // why passes if there is string inside?
}
```

[Sandbox here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/DYUwLgBGIM5gXBAdgVwLYCMQCcDaBdCAXglwEYAaCAJioGYqByAQ0cIHp2IBjAe22whuYYAE8IAM2YBLYDACwAKCWhI0ONWIQA3koj6IAExBpeiSnoPToaGIgA8qTDgIA+Ui0ZMMbKpx78gsJikjJySgC+SirgULBgdFq6igZGJmYQFilWNnYQjuhYePju5FS0EAwQnvh+XADuABbiAA7MMDCwENISUI04IN0wEHDY0kgA5t1IMNLGAPyRSkA)

Why it passes if there is at least one correct value type, and allows rest to be wrong? How to make sure that **ALL** Array values in object item are certain type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `test` is somewhat different from what you're using compared to `test2` and `test3`. This:

```
let test: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 'a']
```

annotates the type of `test`: it requires that `test` be `number[]`. The array being assigned to it does not fulfill that type, so it fails.

Your second and third examples are something completely different, which is *type assertion*. Type assertion with `<>` or `as` is basically telling TypeScript: "I know what I'm doing, this expression *is* of the type `SomeType`, even if the type-checker can't determine that from the context.

For a similar example, the following is permitted:

```
const something = localStorage.foobar as number;
```

or, equivalently

```
const something = <number> localStorage.foobar;
```

even though localStorage does not have a `foobar` property which is a number. (Local storage properties are either strings or functions) With `as` and `<>`s, you're *asserting the type*, regardless of what TS can inference, not *checking the type*.

The second example with `test2` fails with the following error message:

> Conversion of type 'string[]' to type 'number[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

It's not failing because the type *isn't assertable*, but because the two types *do not sufficiently overlap*.

The `test3` passes because `Array<number | string>` does have some overlap with `Array<number>`.

To fix it and have both test2 and test3 fail as desired, go back to the syntax you're using with the first example, of putting the type after a colon right after the variable name:

```
let test3: {
    demo: number;
    items: number[];
} = {
    demo: 1,
    items: [1, 2, 3, 'a'], // This fails - good!
}
```

so that TypeScript's type checker will check it properly, and result in a typing error, without doing any type-assertion.